# Some of approximations related to integrals and elliptic functions

Tags: improper-integrals, special-functions, elliptic-integrals, elliptic-functions, approximate-integration

> I have just known about the elliptic functions and I saw three nice examples as following :

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\tan x}{4\ln^{2}\tan x+ \pi^{2}}{\rm d}x\cong\frac{1}{4}$$
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{{\rm d}x}{\sqrt{1- x^{3}}}\cong\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{3}}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{4\sqrt{3}- 6}}\frac{{\rm d}x}{\sqrt{1- x^{2}}\sqrt{1- \frac{\sqrt{3}+ 2}{4}\cdot x^{2}}}$$
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{3}}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{3}}\frac{{\rm d}y{\rm d}x}{\sin^{2}x+ \cos^{2}y}\cong\frac{4}{\pi}$$
I'm looking forward to similar problems, any comments and solutions are welcome and appreciated

Thanks a real lot !

Comment: Maybe you can search similar problems.

Comment: Searching for this kind of approximations is entertaining, but hardly useful. I would also suggest providing the desired accuracy to which they should work. 1-3 digits is not very interesting, so something like 10 digits or more?

Comment: If you're interested in approximations related to elliptic integrals, you'll want to play with their relation to the AGM iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substitution
$$x=\arctan y$$
presents the first integral in the form of
$$\int\limits_0^\infty \dfrac{y\,\text d y}{(4\ln^2y+\pi^2)(1+y^2)} = \dfrac14$$
(see [WA integration](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5Einfty%20t%2F%28%284%20ln%20%5E2%20t%20%2Bpi%5E2%29%281%2Bt%5E2%29%29dt)).